# python patch object that is under __init__.py

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I'm writing a test and I want to mock a list that is located in `__init__.py`, meaning not under a class. 
The object reference is:
`project/app/management/commands/__init__.py`

and `__init__.py` looks something like:

```
my_list_of_dict = [
{
    'name': 'option1',
    'vesion': 0,

},
{
    'name': 'option1',
    'vesion': 0,

}
]
```

If it was under a class I would do something like -

```
@mock.patch.object(Class, 'my_list_of_dict')
```

but it isn't the case.

I tried something like

```
@mock.patch('project.app.management.commands.my_list_of_dict')
def test(self, mock_list):
    mock_list.return_value = [{.....}]
```

But it didn't work.

EDIT:

Adding info about the test

This is the test:

```
@mock.patch('project.app.management.commands.my_list_of_dict')
def test_run_command_with_parameters(self, mock_list_of_dict):
    mock_list_of_dict.return_value = [
                                        {
                                            'name': 'other_name',
                                            'vesion': 1
                                        }
    ]
    with mock.patch('django.core.management.call_command', return_value=True,
                    side_effect=None) as call_command_mock:
        c = Command()
        c.handle()
```

This is part of the Command:

```
from . import my_list_of_dict

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for dict in my_list_of_dict:
        .....
```

Now, when the test get to the `handle()` part - it gets the original value, and not the mocked one

Comment: Remember you always need to patch where it is used, not where it is defined.

Comment: Note that you need to import the corresponding module as well. Then the mock should work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I think that's my problem. Could you please elaborate? In the test it seems like the patch is working - it shows that the object equals to the mock, but when the function (Command.handle()) calls that object in the test - it gets the original value and not the mocked one.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the correct path to your `commands` module.

Edit (first example was wrong sorry):

Suppose that tests are inside `project`, in a `tests` folder, maybe in `some_tests.py` (and `project` folder and every subfolder has a `__init__.py` inside). Also you invoke tests for example with `python -m discover` from the `project` folder.

```
from unittest import mock
from unittest import TestCase

import app.management.commands # only needed for 2nd assert

class TestCase1(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('app.management.commands.my_list_of_dict')
    def test(self, mock_list):
        mock_list.return_value = [None]
        self.assertEqual(mock_list(), [None])
        self.assertEqual(app.management.commands.my_list_of_dict(),
                         [None])
```

This works over here now.
Patch requires the right path with a class or module name followed by the attribute to patch.

Comment: Hi @progmatico, I tried it. I'm getting an error from mock.py - `thing = __import__(import_path)
ImportError: No module named 'commands' `

Comment: @user2880391 Edited again just for a better example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't get an error now, but it seems like the mock doesn't work... when that list is accessed - it gets the original value (not the mocked one)

Comment: Ok, I realized that that mock does work (your example works), but in the test - the function that uses that list gets the original value, not the mocked one

Comment: @user2880391 Can you edit to show how the test is written?

Comment: Seems like when getting the object in the test - I do get the mocked list, but that function calls a `Command.handle()` function the imports that list. when the test gets to that point where the function calls that list (in the Command.handle()) - it receives the original value and not the mocked one

Comment: @user2880391 Have you read the Django manual on testing custom management commands with `call_command()` on page 352 and section 4.2 on page 537. I understand what the problem is (like you do) but I suspect you shouldn't be testing the command that way. Also your list of dicts resembles command options...

Comment: @user2880391 Maybe this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889914/custom-django-management-command-with-appended-parameters) helps.